# best free iOS plotting frameworks?

Tags: ios, graphs

Any recommendations? I've tried to get comfortable with CorePlot the past two weeks and build something simple, but I can't get it to work with Apple's new 64-bit requirements - no matter how I play around with the build settings I can't have an app with Core Plot that passes validation for the App store. I'm newish to ios (6 months of fooling around from time to time), but I have struggled inordinately with installing (not using) CorePlot and so I'm hoping there's a lighter framework out there that's easier to install and get past the 64-bit app store requirement. Any recommendations? All I need are line graphs, scatter plots, and nothing else. No particular bells and whistles needed either as far as aesthetics.

Comment: Have a look at this thread [drawing graphs in iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5065416/what-are-the-alternatives-to-core-plot-for-drawing-graphs-in-iphone-sdk).

Comment: @Vembu thanks for the link. I had seen that post, but it's quite out of date and includes some packages for which you have to pay thousands of dollars to use. Also that post does not address the newly introduced (as of Feb 2015) 64-bit compatibility requirement for the ios App store.